# SAP Business One - > Rest API for embedded incident

Tags: node.js, api, rest, sapb1

Based on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1ynn2CH0Pc&list=LL&index=1&t=3s
I'm looking for a rest api in order to create/modifiy/read incident with SAP B1, however no documentation seems to be available for my issue.

I've found the following node module https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sapb1 but it's not clear if is fit for my purpose.

Any idea?

Comment: look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaF_i7x9-s0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API for SAP Business One is "Service Layer". Latest documentation: https://help.sap.com/doc/6ab840ef2e8140f3af9eeb7d8fef9f06/10.0/en-US/Working_with_SAP_Business_One_Service_Layer.pdf

I am not sure what you mean by "incident" - do you mean Service Calls or Activities? If so, Service Layer exposes both of these objects. You can also perform CRUD operations on user tables/objects.

The Node module you found is a wrapper for Service Layer, I haven't used it. You can just access SL directly with a http client if you wish.

Comment: Yeah, I mean Activities. Thanks a lot!