# SAP B1 - Service Layer on-premise availability

Tags: api, odata, service-layer, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

Related at this question [SAP Business One - > Rest API for embedded incident](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68440914/sap-business-one-rest-api-for-embedded-incident), I'd like to know if Service Layer (REST API in OData format) is available both on-premise and cloud solution.
From many different documents I've already seen it's not clear if there's some differents between on-premise and cloud solution, so I need to be sure service layer API is always available
regardless of infrastructure.

Comment: I thought it was but your question makes me doubt.